# Snapping section only on one section of website

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, fullpage.js, snapping

I have seen many websites recently that are incorporating the scrolling from section to section like [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) and I am trying to achieve this on only one section of a page, like this page [wedding party app](http://www.weddingpartyapp.com).Does anyone know how I could achieve this? I've had no luck in finding something that can help me recreate the snapping section with the iPhone.... I will be making my own animations.

Answer (score 0):

***this is very easy***

html

```
<div id="skrollr-wrapper">
    <div id="box1">box1</div>
    <div id="box2">box2</div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/dist/skrollr.min.js"></script>
```

css

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff fixed url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgAQMAAABJtOi3AAAABlBMVEX4+Pj09PQf/c7fAAAAGklEQVR4Xq3MIQEAAADDIPqX/kvMIMEWEm8O7b0/wewc/NcAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat;
}

#skrollr-wrapper {
  /* make sure the boxes stay in place while you 
     scroll by wrapping them in this fixed div: */
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#skrollr-wrapper div {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

#box1 {
  background: blue;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;  bottom: 0;
}

#box2 {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

jquery

```
// setSkrollr function extracted from https://www.pingdom.com/2013/
var setSkrollr = function($el, data) {
    for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
        var d = data[i],
            px = d[0];
            css = d[1];
        $el.attr('data-' + px, css);
    }
}

jQuery(function($) {
    setSkrollr($('#box1'), [[0, 'width:100%'], [1500, 'width:0%']]);
    setSkrollr($('#box2'), [[0, 'transform:translateX(-100%)'], [750, 'transform:translateX(100%)'], [1500, 'transform:translateX(-100%)']]);

    skrollr.init({
        smoothScrolling: false
    });
});
```

Comment: I was mainly talking about how the whole page snaps just for that part of the animation. Thanks so much for the iPhone animation though it will come in handy. Do you have any idea on how they accomplished the snapping between sections only for that part and then stops after it gets to "works with all wedding guest...."?

Comment: i really appreciate the help by the way. I get how to do that switching from relative to fixed. But I don't understand how to get the actual scrolling part to work in sections. as you scroll it automatically scrolls from section to section while animating.